# Web service Java EE

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'am asking if there is a tutorial about implementing a web service with Java EE (SGBD --> JDBC --> JPA --> DAO --> web service) the under Tomcat Apache server.

Comment: How is the webservice implemented, for example, using Spring, JAX-WS or axis?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is correct:

```
Java EE (SGBD --> JDBC --> JPA --> DAO --> web service)
```

I don't know what SGBD is.   Can you clarify?

I think it's either JDBC or JPA as the DAO implementation, but not both.  Yes, I realize that all relational database access is via JDBC in Java, but JPA implies an ORM or JDO solution to me, not straight JDBC.

Here's the Spring [web service tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html) and Spring [MVC step-by-step](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I use Oracle 10g database, and in our university, we've seen this architecture and they told us that the JPA contains the JDBC layer ... one other question please, how can I use an Android, Blackberry mobile Client for Spring web service ? thanks one more time :)